# Failed to load Chrome extension

Tags: json, manifest

I can't figure out this error. I followed Chrome tutorial, but I can't find it.

```
{
  "name": "tracking",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest.version": 2,
  "description": "tracking students",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

```
Failed to load extension
File
~/Desktop/Chrome extension
Error
The 'manifest_version' key must be present and set to 2 (without quotes). See developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html for details.
Could not load manifest.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `manifest.version` (with dot delimiter) key in your JSON config, but you should have `manifest_version` (with underscore delimiter) key:

```
{
  "name": "tracking",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "tracking students",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  }
}
```